# Multiple aggregate queries based on WHERE

Tags: mysql, group-by

This is probably something super simple....
But right now I can't think of how to do it in one statement.

I know I can SELECT count(id) WHERE status  = APP, and repeat for all counts. But I would like to complete it in one query.
Would I group by city and then group by Status, and Sum?

Table is as follows....

```
City  |  Status  |  
City 1    APP
City 1    NH
City 1    APP
City 1    NEW
City 2    NEW
City 2    APP
City 2    APP
City 2    NH
```

I want to return the following array.

```
 {[cityname]=>City1,[Total]=>4,[APP]=>1,[NH]=>1,[NEW]=>2}, 
 {[cityname]=>City2,[Total]=>4,[APP]=>2,[NH]=>1,[NEW]=>1}
```

My current queries are...

```
 SELECT COUNT(id) as total, city WHERE status = 'APP' GROUP BY city
 SELECT COUNT(id) as total, city WHERE status = 'NH' GROUP BY city
 SELECT COUNT(id) as total, city WHERE status = 'NEW' GROUP BY city
```

I know this is extremely simple, but its been a while, and I forget how exactly to combine  these into one statement.

Comment: I am, I am using GROUP BY city

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a row per city with `APP`, `NH`, `NEW` being columns you can use conditional `SUM()` like this

```
SELECT city,
       COUNT(*) total, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'APP' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) app,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'NH'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) nh,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'NEW' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) new
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY city
```

Output:

```
|   CITY | TOTAL | APP | NH | NEW |
|--------|-------|-----|----|-----|
| City 1 |     4 |   2 |  1 |   1 |
| City 2 |     4 |   2 |  1 |   1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46f07/2)** demo

Answer (score 2):

You can group by city and status as well

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as total, city, status  GROUP BY city, status
```

Comment: "Then the object creation will need to be done on the application side, and can't be easily done on the sql side", is what I think you meant to add to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorthand method that only works in `MySQL`

```
SELECT City,
       COUNT(*) Total, 
       SUM(Status = 'APP') APP,
       SUM(Status = 'NH') NH,
       SUM(Status = 'NEW') `NEW`
FROM   TableName
GROUP  BY City
```